# Reading config files on GAE classpath

Tags: java, google-app-engine, io, filesystems

I understand that you cannot access `java.io.File` from a GAE app (its restricted). However, I remember reading somewhere that it's possible to have access to anything in your WAR (perhaps anything under `WEB-INF/`?).

So I ask: **is there a way to access a file inside your WAR from a GAE app?** In other words, if I deploy a WAR with the following structure:

```
MyApp/
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        appengine-web.xml
        ...etc.

        my-special-config.xml
```

Is there any way for me to read `my-special-config.xml` from inside my GAE app? If so, how and with what classes? I see in the GAE SDK that there is an `AppEngineFile`, and wondering if I can use this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the dev guide [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox):

> ### The Filesystem
>
> A Java application cannot use any classes used to write to the filesystem, such as java.io.FileWriter. An application can read its own files from the filesystem using classes such as java.io.FileReader. An application can also access its own files as "resources", such as with [Class.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [ServletContext.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).
>
> Only files that are considered "resource files" are accessible to the application via the filesystem. By default, all files in the WAR are "resource files." You can exclude files from this set using the [appengine-web.xml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig) file.

Sample code to read resource file under classpath in POJO class:

```
String file = "/WEB-INF/my-special-config.xml";
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

Sample code to read resource file under classpath in Servlet class:

```
String file = "/WEB-INF/my-special-config.xml";
InputStream in = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can by using just the File class like this:

```
    String FileName = "my-special-config.xml";
    File file = new File(FileName);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/SDPm_HJcMaQ).

Comment: Where does the file should be located?

Comment: @kilaka the same place as in the original question.